What is this SMD common mode choke?
A pair of components was accidentally destroyed on my Korg Volca Modular synth:

Through the magic of getting another identical synth, I was able to see how it is supposed to be on a working unit:
Since they are connected to an ADP5071 positive/negative switching voltage regulator operating at 1.2 MHz, I was able to figure the nature of these components with (a lot of) help from more adept engineers. They are a common mode choke and a silicon diode, with the diode bridging the right side of the two coils as in the following half-assed schematic:
My measurements are as follows:

in multimeter diode testing mode, putting the common at the diode's north end and the red input at the south end (relative to the picture), I measure a continuous 0.538V which is a good sign if I'm not mistaken that it's a silicon diode. In the other direction it's a 0L which is why I am about certain it's a silicon diode.
using the same mode at the two south poles (resp. north poles) (relative to the picture again) of the mystery choke, I measure about 1V when continuity is established and it beeps and then it falls quickly to 0V (in about 1 second).

However, I can't figure the exact model for that common mode choke and I'd like to get one to similar with similar specs. Using a caliper I was able to measure it at 5.0 or 5.1mm and about 3 mm in height.
What are the exact components I need to fix my broken unit and how can I know? The only extra info I have is the marking "06 Yx" or "106 Yx" on that choke.

The missinv two pin component looks like a capacitor, not a diode.

Capacitor for sure.

"06 Yx" or "106 Yx" can correspond to a specific series or value in the manufacturer’s catalog.

It's probably a Sagami TQR5027C-N0006RN2 common mode choke.

I think it's likely the N0006RN2, because of the 06 marking. This datasheet from the official homepage doesn't show markings, but I found an older one that does. They look a bit different, but very close in style.


(Source: inductor.com)

That's absolutely it, you showed excellent skill. Do you have an idea what part could be fit as replacement as this has been obsoleted, apparently?

@MatDee I don't think the part is obsolete, but availability seems bad. The footprint is pretty unusual, so finding a drop-in replacement will probably be difficult.

@MatDee Maybe the Bourns SRF0504-302Y could work.
